# Quoted CMake external objects path produces linker error

Tags: gcc, cmake, yagarto

i 'm trying to build a simple main.project with YAGARTO, Cmake and Ecplise. 
The problem is that CMake quotes the path of my both sources:

```
add_executable(icejupi.elf main.c startup_stm32f10x_hd.s)
```

like this (automatically genrated from CMAKE in build.make)

```
myProj_elf_OBJECTS = \
"CMakeFiles/myProj.elf.dir/main.c.obj" \
"CMakeFiles/myProj.elf.dir/startup_stm32f10x_hd.s.obj"
```

This kind of path quoting produced the following Linker-error:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to tell CMake to not quoting the source-pathes??

Comment: How do you know that it is quoting that is causing the linker error?

Comment: well, you are right its not quoting, its the generated makefile. cause when i start the compiler through CMD-Line with the same arguments as Cmake-Makefile does it works fine. so i guess there is something wrong with the makefile. Cmake buil my object-files in his own folder "..\CMakefiles\(Projname).elf.dir" is there anyway to tell cmake to creat the object-files in the same dir as the source-files??? thanks

Comment: No, CMake places objects in a separate location for a reason.  Might I recommend you post your entire CMakeLists.txt file?  I have a feeling that there is something in there that is not correct.  Also, you can take a look at what CMake is doing when you run `make` by typing `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: is the yagarto-Make really compatible with Unix-Makefile?

Comment: @SethMMorton the Problem was that the Yagarto-Make is not 
compatible with Unix-Makefiles. i changed the settings of Cmake so it genrates MinGW-Makefiels and see it works fine also with yagarto-Make

Comment: I see.  I was unaware the two are not compatible.  Sorry, I have no experience with that make system.

Comment: me too. i m just trying to get familiar with it. ;)